# Pursuit problem with bounds on acceleration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, recreational-mathematics

Suppose a predator is pursuing a prey, both individuals are modelled as point particles moving in a Euclidean plane or in Euclidean space. The predator and prey have a respective upper bound $a_P, a_p>0$ on their magnitude of their acceleration. They also have a respective upper bound $v_P, v_p>0$ on their speed. Finally there is of course their initial separation $D>0$. For which values of $(D,v_P,v_p,a_P,a_p)$ is the predator able to catch the prey?

(I forgot to say something about their initial velocity... be free to discuss this if it matters for the outcome. Of course initial speeds exceeding the aforementioned bounds are forbidden.)

Comment: It kind of depends on the model of acceleration. Can the actors maintain peak acceleration up to peak speed, or is there a tradeoff? For mechanical systems, there is a linear tradeoff for electric motors and a power tradeoff for combustion motors. For biological systems there is kind of stepped tradeoff that requires more definitions than described above. It also depends if the predator can cut corners to make ground.

Comment: I think my question is clear on that: there is no speed-dependent reduction in the magnitude of the acceleration until the peak speed is actually reached (and even then the bound on acceleration is de facto directional and not a magnitude bound). I don't know what you mean by cutting corners.

Comment: It is not clear if the actual acceleration depends on speed. I understand the peak magnitude is fixed, but I think you are eluding that if it were in a straight line, the predator is going to acceleration _at peak magnitude_ until it reaches peak speed and then their acceleration is going to be zero.

Comment: Cutting corner talks about how easy it is to change direction of travel, and if the predator can target a location ahead of the pray, or is it _always_ traveling in the direction the pray is now.

Comment: This is all covered in the question as it is posed: the "serious" definition of the acceleration of a point particle with time-dependent position $x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is $\ddot{x}(t)$. That should answer your questions.

Comment: So e.g. for the predator we require at all times $|\dot{x}_P(t)|<v_P$ and $|\ddot{x}_P(t)|<a_P$